# How to configure storage.smallFiles on mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a CentOS machine where I installed mongodb and I want it to always use storage.smallFiles setting, so I went to `/etc` and I created a new file `/etc/mongodb.conf` where I added the following text and I saved:

```
storage:
   smallFiles:
      enabled: true
```

then I typed:

```
$ mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf
Unrecognized option: storage.smallFiles.enabled
try 'mongod --help' for more information
```

I followed documentation on http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.smallFiles

Answer (score 48):

The configuration for storage option `smallFiles` is different for different versions of MongoDB. Note that MMAPv1 storage engine is deprecated in MongoDG v4.0 and removed in MongoDB v4.2 - [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/configuration-options/#removed-mmapv1-options).

**MongoDB 3.0–4.0** - [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/configuration-options/#storage.mmapv1.smallFiles):

```
storage:
  mmapv1:
    smallFiles: true
```

**MongoDB 2.6** - [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/reference/configuration-options/#storage.smallFiles):

```
storage:
   smallFiles: true
```

**MongoDB 2.4** - [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.4/reference/configuration-options/#smallfiles):

```
smallfiles = true
```

You can check that your setting is properly set by calling this command against `admin` database:

```
db.runCommand({getCmdLineOpts:1});
```

You can also specify it directly when starting `mongod`:

```
mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf --smallFiles
```

Comment: in mongodb 2.6.10, I had to use `smallfiles = true`

Comment: @jtbr maybe you were still using the old format from 2.4. Mongo 2.6 introduced YAML-based configuration file format. Old format remains for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

If you're a developer, don't have time and is using a VM getting out of space... Just copy, paste and go!

```
sudo bash -c "echo \"smallfiles=true\" >> /etc/mongodb.conf"
sudo service mongodb restart
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using mongodb: 3.0.

You need to set the Option Hierarchy as storage.mmapv1.smallFiles : true

```
storage:
  mmapv1:
    smallFiles: true
```

Take care of the spaces in your yaml file.

Example:

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: true
  mmapv1:
    smallFiles: true
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting this error with mongodb 4.2 then it is because some of the options are removed in **Mongo DB 4.2**

```
Removed Configuration File Setting           Removed Command-line Option
storage.mmapv1.journal.commitIntervalMs  
storage.mmapv1.journal.debugFlags              mongod --journalOptions
storage.mmapv1.nsSize                          mongod --nssize
storage.mmapv1.preallocDataFiles               mongod --noprealloc
storage.mmapv1.quota.enforced                  mongod --quota
storage.mmapv1.quota.maxFilesPerDB             mongod --quotaFiles
storage.mmapv1.smallFiles                      mongod --smallfiles
storage.repairPath                             mongod --repairpath
replication.secondaryIndexPrefetch             mongod --replIndexPrefetch
```

Please refer [Mongodb 4.2 Release Notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.2/)